# 内積計算の高速化

Tags: python, python3, numpy

Python3で作成した内積を計算するプログラムの高速化を検討しております。

下記ソースコードの以下の部分がボトルネックとなっております。

```
dat0 = list(map(lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y), cvec.T, d_vec))
```

ここは内積を計算する部分です。この部分を高速化することは可能でしょうか？
なお、試しにCythonでやってみましたが、エラーが出力されました。Cythonではlamdaはサポートされていないようです。
お手数ですが、ご助力頂けると大変助かります。

```
import numpy as np
import time as t

np.random.seed(0)
xyz = np.random.rand(4, 100000, 3)
vec = np.random.rand(3, 100000)

def main():

    start = t.time()

    x = np.array(xyz[:, :, 0])
    y = np.array(xyz[:, :, 1])
    z = np.array(xyz[:, :, 2])

    cvec = vec[:, :]

    p0 = np.array([x.T, y.T, z.T])
    p0 = [p0[:, i, :] for i in range(100000)]
    p_ref = np.array([x[0], y[0], z[0]])
    d_vec = p0 - np.repeat(p_ref, 4).reshape(100000, 3, 4)

    dat0 = list(map(lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y), cvec.T, d_vec))

    print('time : ' + str(round((t.time() - start),5)) + ' [sec]')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/184121

Comment: 回答がついていて成果があると思うのですが、質問を修正し更に回答を募るのはおかしいと思います。このままではズルズルと回答⇔質問を繰り返して終わりの見えない状況になると思うので一度承認してはいかがでしょうか？また、目標の具体的な処理数値などがあるのであればソレを提示することでより具体的な高速化の回答を得られるかと思います。なんにせよ、一度承認し、別質問を立てることを推奨します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10902

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。一旦承認したいと思います。10倍以上の高速化を望んでいました。言葉足らずでした。

Comment: 質問をロールバックし、追記前の状態に戻しました。

Comment: すみません、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1案ですが、`numpy.einsum`を使って以下のようにするのはどうでしょうか。
計算結果の形式がarrayのlistではなく、多次元のarrayにはなりますが。
(以下のコードの`new_dat0`は元のコードの`dat0`を`np.array()`で型変換したものと等しいはずです)。

```
def main():

    start = t.time()

    x = np.array(xyz[:, :, 0])
    y = np.array(xyz[:, :, 1])
    z = np.array(xyz[:, :, 2])

    cvec = vec[:, :]

    p0 = np.array([x.T, y.T, z.T])
    p0 = [p0[:, i, :] for i in range(100000)]
    p_ref = np.array([x[0], y[0], z[0]])
    d_vec = p0 - np.repeat(p_ref, 4).reshape(100000, 3, 4)

    #dat0 = np.array(list(map(lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y), cvec.T, d_vec))) 
    new_dat0 = np.einsum("ij,ijk->ik", cvec.T, d_vec)

    print('time : ' + str(round((t.time() - start),5)) + ' [sec]')
```

私の手元の環境※だと実行時間の差は以下になりました。
元々のコード：time : 0.22087 [sec]
新しいコード：time : 0.10792 [sec]

※python 3.7.2, numpy 1.16.2

Comment: ありがとうございます！私の環境でも2倍程速くなりました。 さらに高速化したく、修正したコードをCythonで書き直し、コンパイルもできました。ただ、Cythonで書き直しても速度は変わらなかったです。。私のCythonの書き方が間違っている可能性がありますでしょうか？もしダメな部分があればご指摘いただけると幸いです。修正したコードを質問欄に追記しておきます。

Comment: 質問の追記ではなく、分けることを検討しては？

Comment: ご指摘がありまして、一旦承認させて頂きます。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！別途、質問を検討いたします。

Comment: ひとまず前に進んだようでなによりです。